# Как связать 2 выпадающих меню между собой по ключу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select, фильтры

Есть 2 выпадающих меню: в первом - выводится марка автомобиля, а во втором, -к каждой марке во вложенности дерева с глубиной `data-sf-depth="1"`? - ее модели. Как сделать списки связанными, чтобы при выборе каждой марки появлялись только ее модели? У меня пока получилось сделать так, что при выборе марки выводятся только модели (но все, а не конкретно ее!), либо не выводится ни одна модель.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var select1 = document.getElementsByClassName("sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat")[0].getElementsByClassName("sf-input-select")[0],
    select2 = document.getElementsByClassName("sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat")[1].getElementsByClassName("sf-input-select")[0],
    opt = [].slice.call(select1.options, 0),
    opt2 = [].slice.call(select2.options, 0);
  var value;
  select1.onchange = function() {
    opt.forEach(function(option, i) {
      if (option.selected) {
        value = option.value;
        return false;
      }
    });
    opt2.forEach(function(option, i) {
      var parent = option.parentNode;
      if (option.classList.contains("sf-level-1") || !i) {
        select2.appendChild(option);
      } else {
        if (parent) {
          parent.removeChild(option);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<li class="sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat" data-sf-field-name="_sft_ad_cat" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="select" data-sf-combobox="1" data-sf-term-rewrite="[&quot;http:\/\/site.com\/ad-category\/[0]\/&quot;]">
  <label>
 <select data-combobox="1" name="_sft_ad_cat[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
  <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">марка а/м</option>
  <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-32" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="alfa-romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-19 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-count="12" data-sf-depth="0" value="audi">Audi</option>  
 </select>
</label>
</li>

<li class="sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat" data-sf-field-name="_sft_ad_cat" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="select" data-sf-combobox="1" data-sf-term-rewrite="[&quot;http:\/\/site.com\/ad-category\/[0]\/&quot;]">
  <label>
 <select data-combobox="1" name="_sft_ad_cat[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
  <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">марка а/м</option>
  <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-32" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="alfa-romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-59" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a6c5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;156</option>
  <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-19" data-sf-count="10" data-sf-depth="0" value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-60" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a6c5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A6C5</option>
  <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-61" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a6c5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A4</option>
  <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-62" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a6c5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A6</option>
 </select>
</label>
</li>
```

Comment: пример не воспроизводится - видимо, css не хватает

Comment: @humster_spb уже воспроизводится

Comment: `opt2.forEach` в этом цикле просто ад какой-то. Почему просто не использовать value из первого селекта (хотя он берется, но не используется)? Можно же просто грохать все опшнс второго при изменении первого, и вливать только актуальные

Comment: "value из первого селекта" ну как не используется - в if же используется. "Можно же просто грохать все опшнс второго при изменении первого, и вливать только актуальные" @Artem Gorlachev ну так, а как это сделать? - в этом же вопрос. Если у вас все просто - покажите это кодом

Comment: не вижу, вижу объявление и присвоение. не могу показать кодом, тк у вас привязки модели к марке вообще нет в html

Comment: `if (option.selected)` ну да, есть только глубина sf-level-0 и sf-level-1, поэтому это и задача

Answer (score 2):

Я бы немного изменил логику: не стал бы в select с моделями дублировать марки, оставил бы там только модели и сделал бы этот select недоступным для выбора, пока не выбрана марка.

Связал бы я два select'а следующим образом: моделям задал бы класс, который соответствует value марки.

```js
$('.cars').change(function(){
   $('.models').prop('selectedIndex', 0); //ощищаем select с моделями при каждом изменении select'а с марками
   var car = $(this).val(); //получаем value выбранной марки
   if(car != '') { //проверяем, выбрана ли хоть какая-то марка
      $('.models').attr('disabled',false); //открываем select с моделями
      $('.models option').css('display','none'); //сначала скрываем все модели
      $('.models option.'+car).css('display','inline'); //затем открываем те, которые нам нужны
   }
   else {
      $('.models').attr('disabled',true); //если не выбрана ни одна марка, скрываем select с моделями
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<select class="cars" name="car_cat[]">
  <option value="">марка а/м</option>
  <option value="alfa-romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<select class="models" name="model_cat[]" disabled>
  <option value="">модель а/м</option>
  <option class="alfa-romeo" value="156">156</option>
  <option class="audi" value="A6C5">A6C5</option>
  <option class="audi" value="A4">A4</option>
  <option class="audi" value="A6">A6</option>
  <option class="nissan" value="Juke">Juke</option>
  <option class="nissan" value="Murano">Murano</option>
</select>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь и хорошие мысли! но, к сожалению, списки создаются динамически и тянутся из базы и поэтому связать и прописать классы  "Связал бы я два select'а следующим образом: моделям задал бы класс, который соответствует value марки." нет возможности.. Понятно, что это бы во многом упростило задачу, а пока же решение вижу, чтобы прорваться через `nextElementSibling`